# Videojs - current index as variable

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have a VideoJs player that plays from a playlist.
I want to display which video number is currently playing from the playlist. Since I need the total number of videos anyway to create the playlist, I can use the defined variable there.

e.g. "Video 3 of 10".

For this I try by means of:

```js
var test = player.currentIndex(videoList);
```

To pass the current number of the video into the variable.
Unfortunately without success.

```js
var lerneinheit = "E1";
var videocounter = 26;
var videonumber= 0;

const videoList = Array.from({ length: videocounter }, (_, i) => {
    return { sources: [{ src: `https://www.XXX.de/player/${lerneinheit}_${videonumber + i + 1}.mp4`, type: 'video/mp4' }], };
});



var player = videojs(document.querySelector('video'), {
  inactivityTimeout: 0
});
try {
  player.volume(1);
} catch (e) {}
player.playlist(videoList);
document.querySelector('.previous').addEventListener('click', function() {
  player.playlist.previous();
});
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', function() {
  player.playlist.next();
});


player.playlist.autoadvance(0); // play all

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name=autoadvance]'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var value = document.querySelector('[name=autoadvance]:checked').value;
    //alert(value);
    player.playlist.autoadvance(JSON.parse(value));
  });
});


/* ADD PREVIOUS */
var Button = videojs.getComponent('Button');

// Extend default
var PrevButton = videojs.extend(Button, {
  //constructor: function(player, options) {
  constructor: function() {
    Button.apply(this, arguments);
    //this.addClass('vjs-chapters-button');
    this.addClass('icon-angle-left');
    this.controlText("Previous");
  },



  handleClick: function() {
    console.log('click');
    player.playlist.previous();
  }
});

/* ADD BUTTON */
//var Button = videojs.getComponent('Button');

// Extend default
var NextButton = videojs.extend(Button, {
  //constructor: function(player, options) {
  constructor: function() {
    Button.apply(this, arguments);
    //this.addClass('vjs-chapters-button');
    this.addClass('icon-angle-right');
    this.controlText("Next");
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    console.log('click');
    player.playlist.next();
  }
});

videojs.registerComponent('NextButton', NextButton);
videojs.registerComponent('PrevButton', PrevButton);
player.getChild('controlBar').addChild('PrevButton', {}, 0);
player.getChild('controlBar').addChild('NextButton', {}, 2);



document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = "Von " + videocounter;
```

Comment: Hi  Your snippets can't be run. You can make normal code blocks out of them. See [syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) from the SO help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [API documentation](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-playlist/blob/main/docs/api.md):

`player.curtentItem()` returns the index of the current item. You'll probably want to increase this by one for display, as it is 0-based. The `playlistitem` event is triggered when the item has changed.